# Android setBackgroundResource acting different in api 16-19

Tags: android, xml, background, android-edittext

I am using setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myXmlFile) and when i run the app in api 21 and above everything its okay but when i run the app in api 16-19 it shows smth different.
In my editText on focus I am trying to change the underline color and for underline I have used a custom xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-3dp"
    android:right="-3dp"
    android:top="-3dp">
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thickness="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1.2dp"
        android:color="#c6c6c6"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
</shape>
</item>
```

this is normal bottom line so without focusing on editText it looks okay like in the picture:

[image]

But after editText gets focus i have another same xml but with white bottom line color, and in setOnFocusChangeListener() method i use:

```
this.email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.error_email) == null)
        {
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                  email.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_bottom_highlighted);
            }
            else
            {
                email.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_bottom);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and i get this result:

[image]

comparison between two states:

[image]

and editText in xml:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/email_input"
        android:hint="Email-i juaj"
        android:textColorHint="@color/fontColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:textColor="@color/fontColor"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/input_bottom_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/logo_login_bottom_margin"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

**Try to get api version and put a if loop**

```
  if (version >= 16 && version <= 19) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
   else
   {
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
```

Comment: But the problem is that i dont know whats causing that behavior

Comment: Have you Checked in different Devices are how

Comment: Yeah, same... It looks that is a problem with api versions, i mean the way that Im doing its not the right one (custom xml method)

Comment: I don't Think so that custom xml makes a problem

Comment: Any other suggest that can help me, or I should try another method